# Does everyone have a phobia?

Tags: psychology

I have heard it said many times that "everyone has a [phobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobia)", an irrational, overwhelming fear of something. Phobias can be anywhere from mildly inconvenient to completely debilitating.

Common phobias include:

> - fear of spiders
> - fear of snakes
> - fear of flying
> - fear of public speaking
> - thinking clowns are really, really, creepy

Uncommon phobias include

> - Amathophobia- Fear of dust.
> - Euphobia- Fear of hearing good news.

An extensive list of other phobias found [here](http://phobialist.com/).

An internet search or walk through almost any bookstore will show you that there is certainly no shortage of available books, videos, self-help programs and therapies aimed at helping people overcome their phobias, whatever they may be.

While phobias are obviously quite common,

**Has it ever been proven that *literally* everyone has a phobia?**

**Have there been any studies done on rate or prevalence?**

Comment: I don't know if everyone has a phobia, but it seems like there is a phobia for __everything__. "_Fear of peanut butter sticking to the roof of the mouth"_ or "_Fear of teenagers"_? Okay, the second one I can understand ;)

Comment: From Wikipedia: "It is possible for an individual to develop a phobia over virtually anything". I think the point here is the distinction between fear and phobia. Phobia is a medical condition that requires treatment, one can be afraid of spiders, but a phobic person would have a full panic attack seeing one. If you ever witnessed a panic attack you would know there a BIG distinction.

Comment: @sklivvz you are correct,and I thought I might run into a problem with the wording because there is a large difference between what the term means in a clinical setting and how it is commonly used.We see the same sort of thing when discussing what the word "theory" means in a scientific context vs its common usage.Also the concept of a phobia is a spectrum, much as you described,ranging in severity from simple fear to a debilitating medical condition.I will edit to clarify that I intended a more colloquial use of the term phobia.Something more along the lines of Indiana Jones and snakes..

Comment: Do psychopaths count? "Some people who engage in violent behavior possess psychopathic personality traits, such as callousness, grandiosity, and **fearlessness**, and presumably engage in such conduct because they care little about others."

Comment: @sklivvz I would say yes. They do fall under the category of everybody. However, I think that when people say things like this, they are generally referring to people who are otherwise neurotypical.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the answer is "Not literally everyone" because there must be some people who have abnormal lack of fear/panic reactions in general - e.g. even if their subconsciousness has a fear of X, it would not be manifested as a physiological panic attack. Don't have examples to back that up so it's a commment.

Comment: I think it would be impossible to prove that everybody has a phobia. I find it highly unlikely that everybody does have a phobia. If you take a logical approach to fear, then anything that may cause harm to you or others would be a legitimate fear and not a phobia (as long as it is not feared to a debilitating extent), I'm afraid of bombs, that's a regular fear. I would say that I do not have any phobias, I tend to take a logical view of fear an assess what could actually happen, and then decide whether to "fear" something and stay away from it, or to carry on in whatever I was doing. There ar

Comment: Does phobia have a clear definition here? Of all the things that you respond to, there will be something that you respond to the most. So how would you distinguish a strong, but non-phobic, respons in person A from a phobic response in a person B but whose phobic state has less pronounced symptoms? "Overwhelming" is kind of subjective and would be hard to distinguish from "the biggest response you've ever had".

Comment: I don't think it is possible to prove that _literally_ everyone has a phobia, as that would require examination of every single person on the planet.  How would you asses if a newborn baby, 10 minutes old, has a phobia or not?

Comment: @fred That is definitely another problem with this claim, because I think that when people say this they are referring to otherwise neurotypical people who are old enough to have had time to develop mentally.I agree that this is a hard question to define, let alone research or analyze, which is precisely what I find so interesting about it. It would stand to reason that the answer would be "no" but how do we prove it?

Comment: As it stands the question is about semantics. What fears do qualify as phobias? I think it would be good if the question would add a definition.

Comment: @Christian as it stands, I'm having problems finiding a way to clarify the issue.  I didn't originally think the concept of phobia would end up being this subjective and hard to define. I do apologize.

Comment: I don't know about phobias, but Penn and Teller once said, ["Everybody got a gris-gris"](http://forums.randi.org/showthread.php?t=51547), where a gris-gris is "some damned silly little irrational belief which we can not or will not let go".

Comment: I'm scared of even reading the answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **[National Institute of Mental Health](http://www.nimh.nih.gov/index.shtml)** (USA) has some **statistics**:

### Specific Phobia

> Specific phobia involves marked and
>   persistent fear and avoidance of a
>   specific object or situation. This
>   type of phobia includes, but is not
>   limited to, the fear of heights,
>   spiders, and flying.

**Among Adults**

[image]

**Among Children**

[image]

### Social Phobia

> Social phobia is characterized by a
>   persistent, intense, and chronic fear
>   of being watched and judged by others
>   and feeling embarrassed or humiliated
>   by their actions. This fear may be so
>   severe that it interferes with work,
>   school, and other activities and may
>   negatively affect the person’s ability
>   to form relationships.

**Among Adults**

[image]

**Among Children**

[image]

---

**Sources:**

> - [National Institute of Mental Health](http://wwwsearch.nimh.nih.gov/?q=phobia+statistics&spell=1&access=p&output=xml_no_dtd&site=internet_collection&ie=UTF-8&client=internet_frontend&proxystylesheet=internet_frontend)
> - [Lifetime prevalence of mental disorders in U.S. adolescents](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20855043)
> - [Prevalence, severity, and comorbidity of 12-month DSM-IV disorders](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15939839)
> - [Lifetime prevalence and age-of-onset distributions of DSM-IV disorders](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15939837)

---

These statistics are based on a [survey](http://www.hcp.med.harvard.edu/ncs/) done in the United States, with a sample of 10,000 respondents.

There have been similar surveys done worldwide under the auspices of the [World Health Organization](http://www.hcp.med.harvard.edu/wmh/), but I don't have that data.

Comment: the definition you cited is the same one I was going by when I wrote the question, however, I failed to take into account that the subjective nature of the perception of fear would make the question very difficult to address.  Thank you for answering the question with more clarity than that which I posed it.

Comment: 3D bar graphs are [STUPID](http://classes.ninabellisio.com/GD3371/tufte.pdf)!